# How to find if there is ....in-addr.arpa delegated?

Tags: bind, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

I have a pool of IP addresses, but reverse DNS does not works. It works if lookup on namserver but does not work on Internet.

I requested registrar to delegate this pool to `ns1.example.com`.
I added `net IN NS ns1.example.com` on domain dns-hosting.
I added PTRs to `ipXXX.net.example.com` to bind running on `ns1.example.com`.

```
# host a.b.c.17
Host 17.26.18.37.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
# dig +short 17.b.c.a.in-addr.arpa.
# dig +short b.c.a.in-addr.arpa.
# dig +short b.c.in-addr.arpa.
```

`dig +short` is empty, without short it points to RIPE.

Comment: Check [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/86501/how-do-you-know-if-reverse-dns-is-setup-correctly-on-your-server). Or use the PTR tool [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on the size of your subnet and the policies of your ISP if they will actually delegate the PTR records to your name servers or only allow you to supply your desired hostnames for the reverse records and they will manage the reverse zone themselves.

Either way you can use the `trace` option in dig to check/verify if the delegation is set up as you expected with: `dig +trace -x your.ip.address`

> +[no]trace .... Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name servers for the name being looked up. >snip< When tracing is enabled, dig makes iterative queries to resolve the name being looked up. It will follow referrals from the
>   root
>    servers, showing the answer from each server that was used to resolve the lookup.

Comment: I get /24 subnet from RIPE agent, not from ISP.
dig show me
`
a.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN SOA pri.authdns.ripe.net. dns.ripe.net. 1388569846 3600 600 864000 7200`

but i need to 
`c.b.a.in-addr.arpa. 30 IN SOA ns1.mydomain. root.mydomain. 1388669094 28800 7200 2419200 86400`

Comment: You did take a look at RIPE's: [how-to-set-up-reverse-delegation](http://www.ripe.net/data-tools/dns/reverse-dns/how-to-set-up-reverse-delegation) then?